# ORACLE USER role to limit user to view and execute function without modifying it

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am sorry for a newbie question. I am creating a readonly user in oracle. I want to limit him just to view and execute a function or procedure. I dont want him to modify those func or proc. Please help me on how to achieve this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- As sysdba:
-- 1) create an user account
create user <username> identified by <password>;
-- 2) allow user to log in
grant create session to <username>;
-- 3) allow user to execute a single procedure in other schema
grant execute on <other_schema.procedure_name> to <username>;
```

Comment: I tried creating user this way and even executed a command to 'GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO RO_USER', however whenever I execute 'SELECT * FROM <table> and USER= 'RO_USER'', I get nothing, any help/input

Answer (score 0):

From SYSDBA user login (from where you created the user), give the following grant :

```
GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO user;
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO user;
```

where user = the username you just created.

Then ,to ensure the user has only read priviledges, check from session_privs that he doesnot have any other priviledge, specifically any  "CREATE" prviledge. To do this , run :

```
select * from session_privs;
```

from the user you just created.

Comment: I don't think there is any seprate priviledge to "View" any procedure as such. How are you trying to view the procedure/function? Which tool are you using?

Comment: As an afterthought, 'Select any table' grant also might be required. updated the answer